# How to permanently activate desired environment upon login to EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, anaconda, conda

I have the following conda list:

```
➜  ~ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
amazonei_mxnet_p36       /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36
aws_neuron_mxnet_p36     /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/aws_neuron_mxnet_p36
aws_neuron_pytorch_p36     /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/aws_neuron_pytorch_p36
aws_neuron_tensorflow_p36     /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/aws_neuron_tensorflow_p36
mxnet_latest_p37         /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37
mxnet_p36                /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36
python3                  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python3
pytorch_latest_p37       /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p37
pytorch_p37              /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37
tensorflow2_latest_p37     /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37
tensorflow2_p37          /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p37
tensorflow_p37           /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p37
```

I want to enable my environment to be set to `tensorflow2_latest_p37`
whenever I login to my AWS account. How can I achieve that?

I tried putting `source activate ensorflow2_latest_p37` in `.zshrc`. But it gave me:
this error message

```
/home/ubuntu/.zshrc:source:7: no such file or directory: activate
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `conda activate <env>`?

Answer (score -2):

To change the activated environment permanently, there is no method except creating a startup script that runs the `conda activate` command.

In ubuntu, in .bashrc file, added the following command:

```
conda activate <env>
```

and then the specified env is getting activated whenever I open a terminal.

**Edited**

I created an ec2 instance in aws and used zsh shell. Inserting the bellow 2 lines in `.zshrc` worked for me:

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate <env_name>
```

Now when I login to my ec2 instance i get my env activated. I hope this will work for you too.

Comment: I get this error `/home/ubuntu/.zshrc:source:6: no such file or directory: conda`

Comment: can you try this one which i edited. it is working in an ubuntu os. otherwise i think we need to put a startup file inside /etc/init/ to execute the `conda activate` command.

Comment: `zsh` doesn't care about `.bashrc`. Not even `bash` itself cares about that file when it's started as a login shell.

Comment: can you tell me more about you os and are you using ec2 instance?

Comment: i created an ec2 in aws with zsh shell and got it working on my end. i have edited the answer have a look, i hope this will work for you too.

Comment: For bash this worked for me.